# I am trying to have this macro include the ability to copy data from multiple worksheets in a workbook but it will only copy from the first worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

This is my data below.
The code works just doesn't fit my requirements. I need to add the functionality that will allow me to pull data from multiple worksheets in 1 workbook but currently it will only pull the data from 1 worksheet in 1 workbook. 
I've included the code to go through different worksheets but as of now the code will only extract data from 1 worksheet in 1 workbook. 
Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, FNum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    ' Change this to the path\folder location of your files.
    MyPath = "C:\Users\mp180423\Desktop\Gas"

    ' Add a slash at the end of the path if needed.
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

' If there are no Excel files in the folder, exit.
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

       ' Fill the myFiles array with the list of Excel files
    ' in the search folder.
    FNum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        FNum = FNum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To FNum)
        MyFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    ' Set various application properties.
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    ' Add a new workbook with one sheet.
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    ' Loop through all files in the myFiles array.
    If FNum > 0 Then
        For FNum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum))
            On Error GoTo 0


            Dim ws As Worksheet

            For Each ws In Worksheets
            ws.Activate
            Debug.Print ws.Name

            Next



            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
                On Error Resume Next

                ' Change this range to fit your own needs.
                With mybook.Worksheets(3)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A15:B20")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    ' If source range uses all columns then
                    ' skip this file.
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the target worksheet."
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        ' Copy the file name in column A.
                        For Each ws In Worksheets
                        ws.Activate
                        Debug.Print ws.Name
                        Next

                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(FNum)
                        End With

                        ' Set the destination range.
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        ' Copy the values from the source range
                        ' to the destination range.
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False

            End If

        Next FNum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

        Range("B1").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$66").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        "Kilowatt hours used Current period"


ExitTheSub:
    ' Restore the application properties.
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With


MsgBox ("Merge Completed.")
End Sub
```

Comment: You need to further explain what you're trying to do - saying "it doesn't work" is not descriptive enough. You have several blocks of code in here which appear to have no functionality at all - twice you loop through all your worksheets, activate them and `Debug.Print` their name to the immediate window, but in your comments you say it copies the file name to column A? You need to cut this question down and make it simpler to understand.

Comment: I'm not the best at this (which you will see if you check out the questions I asked - and received excellent help for...) but you have the for loop to do worksheets then right after that you limit it to mybook.worksheets(3). At least that is my reading of it...

Comment: I rolled back the edit which removed your code because that made the question even worse and the answer impossible to relate to the question.

Answer (score 1):

I expect that the single worksheet from the single workbook which this code **was** correctly working for, would be the only workbook with at least 3 worksheets.

When selecting the range you have:

```
With mybook.Worksheets(3)
    Set sourceRange = .Range("A15:B20")
End With
```

Note that this restricts the data to the range from only the 3rd (third) worksheet from every workbook.

Also note that on the line prior, you have:

```
On Error Resume Next
```

This would effectively mask the errors coming from attempting to extract data from all the non-existing 3rd worksheets. For the workbook with at least 3 worksheets, since the `With mybook.Worksheets(3)` is hard-coded into your code, this was the only worksheet the data was pulled from.

(And the reason it wasn't duplicated for each worksheet in that workbook, is because the cycles through the worksheets were restricted to the `Debug.Print` lines. The code for the data-moving only cycled through once for each workbook)

Below, you will see three (3) sections:

1. Change Details.

   - This is to help high-light the changes I made to your code so that it cycles through the data-moving for each worksheet, pulling once from each worksheet.
2. Corrected

   - This is for ease of copy/pasting the code
3. Original

   - This is to maintain a copy of the original code I based my answer off of (in case of changes).

---

**Change Details**

From original:

```
Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum))
On Error GoTo 0


Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets
ws.Activate
Debug.Print ws.Name

Next
```

> ```
> If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
> ```

```
    On Error Resume Next

     ' Change this range to fit your own needs.
     With mybook.Worksheets(3)
          Set sourceRange = .Range("A15:B20")
     End With
```

Changed to:

```
Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum))
On Error GoTo 0

Dim ws As Worksheet
```

> ```
> If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
> ```

```
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        On Error Resume Next

        ' Change this range to fit your own needs.
        With ws
            Set sourceRange = .Range("A15:B20")
        End With
```

- Top-half:

  - Although I kept the `Dim ws As Worksheet`, I removed the Debug.Print cycle through all worksheets, as it had no effect on any other code.
- Lower-half:

  - Added a `For Each ws In Worksheets` around the functional code ***(which required adding `Next ws` above `mybook.Close savechanges:=False`)***, and shifted the *with* statement from `With mybook.Worksheets(3)` to `With ws`

Since there was another extraneous `Debug.Print` cycle right before the file name was added to column A, I replaced it with `Debug.Print ws.Name & ": #" & FNum` to be a bit more informative.

---

**Corrected**

---

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, FNum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    ' Change this to the path\folder location of your files.
    MyPath = "C:\Users\mp180423\Desktop\Gas"

    ' Add a slash at the end of the path if needed.
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

' If there are no Excel files in the folder, exit.
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

       ' Fill the myFiles array with the list of Excel files
    ' in the search folder.
    FNum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        FNum = FNum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To FNum)
        MyFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    ' Set various application properties.
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    ' Add a new workbook with one sheet.
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    ' Loop through all files in the myFiles array.
    If FNum > 0 Then
        For FNum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            ' Added cycle through worksheets
            Dim ws As Worksheet
            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
                For Each ws In Worksheets

                    On Error Resume Next

                     ' Change this range to fit your own needs.
                    ' Shifted reference to current worksheet-of-interest
                    With ws
                        Set sourceRange = .Range("A15:B20")
                    End With

                    If Err.Number > 0 Then
                        Err.Clear
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    Else
                        ' If source range uses all columns then
                        ' skip this file.
                        If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                            Set sourceRange = Nothing
                        End If
                    End If
                    On Error GoTo 0

                    If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                        SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                        If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                            MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the target worksheet."
                            BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                            mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                            GoTo ExitTheSub
                        Else

                            ' Prints file name and index number in immediate window.
                            Debug.Print ws.Name & ": #" & FNum

                            ' Copy the file name in column A.
                            With sourceRange
                                BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                        Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(FNum)
                            End With

                            ' Set the destination range.
                            Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                            ' Copy the values from the source range
                            ' to the destination range.
                            With sourceRange
                                Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                            End With
                            destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                            rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                        End If
                    End If
                'Cycles through next worksheet-of-interest
                Next ws
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False

            End If
        Next FNum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

        Range("B1").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$66").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        "Kilowatt hours used Current period"


ExitTheSub:
    ' Restore the application properties.
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With


MsgBox ("Merge Completed.")
End Sub
```

**Original**

---

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, FNum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    ' Change this to the path\folder location of your files.
    MyPath = "C:\Users\mp180423\Desktop\Gas"

    ' Add a slash at the end of the path if needed.
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

' If there are no Excel files in the folder, exit.
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

       ' Fill the myFiles array with the list of Excel files
    ' in the search folder.
    FNum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        FNum = FNum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To FNum)
        MyFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    ' Set various application properties.
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    ' Add a new workbook with one sheet.
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    rnum = 1

    ' Loop through all files in the myFiles array.
    If FNum > 0 Then
        For FNum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum))
            On Error GoTo 0


            Dim ws As Worksheet

            For Each ws In Worksheets
            ws.Activate
            Debug.Print ws.Name

            Next



            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
                On Error Resume Next

                ' Change this range to fit your own needs.
                With mybook.Worksheets(3)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A15:B20")
                End With

                If Err.Number > 0 Then
                    Err.Clear
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                Else
                    ' If source range uses all columns then
                    ' skip this file.
                    If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                        Set sourceRange = Nothing
                    End If
                End If
                On Error GoTo 0

                If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the target worksheet."
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        ' Copy the file name in column A.
                        For Each ws In Worksheets
                        ws.Activate
                        Debug.Print ws.Name
                        Next

                        With sourceRange
                            BaseWks.Cells(rnum, "A"). _
                                    Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(FNum)
                        End With

                        ' Set the destination range.
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum)

                        ' Copy the values from the source range
                        ' to the destination range.
                        With sourceRange
                            Set destrange = destrange. _
                                            Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                        End With
                        destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End If
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False

            End If

        Next FNum
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

        Range("B1").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter
        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$C$66").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:= _
        "Kilowatt hours used Current period"


ExitTheSub:
    ' Restore the application properties.
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With


MsgBox ("Merge Completed.")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @dwirony  Thanks for your reply. twice you loop through all your worksheets, activate them and Debug.Print their name to the immediate window, but in your comments you say it copies the file name to column A? You need to cut this question down and make it simpler to understand.

Comment: Hi @dwirony  Thanks for your reply. I am trying to figure out where to loop through the code so that it will take data from range "A15:B20" from a workbook. Basically I need the code to go through a designated folder and pull data from workbooks. My problem is some workbooks have 1 worksheet and some have more than 1 worksheet. For the workbooks with more than 1 worksheet, the code wont pull in data from the multiple worksheets and will only pull data from the first worksheet in the workbook. The reason I included the loops are to try and go through the workbooks to run the working code.

Comment: @ Mistrella Thanks for this, I tried to implement your changes and am getting a compile error: "Invalid Next Control Variable Reference" with the Next ws at the end.

Comment: @MikeP. I made an edit. I had accidentally put the `Next ws` on the wrong line. I tested it again, and it worked for me with a straight copy/paste this time.

Comment: Plus 1 from me, thanks for confirming what I thought I understood !

Comment: @Mistrella Currently the code will extract data from 1 worksheet in 1 workbook. My goal is to be able to extract data from multiple worksheet in 1 workbook, I added the loop function as I thought it would help me accomplish my goal. The code currently works for 1 worksheet extract from 1 workbook but i'm trying to add the loop function to apply that same code to 3 worksheets in 1 workbook for example. thanks for your help!

Comment: @MikeP.  Verifying: you tried my updated code, and it was only extracting data from one worksheet in one workbook? How many workbooks are in the folder specified (`C:\Users\mp180423\Desktop\Gas`) ?

Comment: @Mistrella I have 11 workbooks in my folder, The code I copied will only extract data from the first worksheet in every workbook. I copied your code under "Corrected without changes formatted differently" I opened a new module and pasted the code and click run and it gives me the same outcome as my original code. Thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: @MikeP. I hadn't paid a lot of attention to when the workbooks were being closed. I edited the code so that the workbook is closed **after** it's done cycling through the worksheets, instead of _before_ getting to the second worksheet in the cycle. I tested it with workbooks with multiple sheets, and it looked like it was behaving correctly. Give it another go?

Comment: @Mistrella the edited code works well! Can you please explain what additional code you added vs what I originally had to make this functionality work correctly? It is extracting the data from multiple worksheets in 1 workbook now so exactly what i'm looking for! You're awesome Mistrella!

Comment: @MikeP. I added a section called **Change Details**, since I thought the explanation a bit long for the comments. Let me know if you would like further detail.

Comment: @Mistrella  Thanks for the change details section. So I compared against the code I originally received (before I added the loops) and your corrected code (there are 3 major things I noticed) 1 was added cycle through worksheets, which I'm okay with, 2. Changed reference to current worksheet, what does (with mybook.worksheet(3)) to (with ws) change? and 3. adding debug.print ws name & " : # " &FNum what is this doing and why was it added? I see it prints file name and index number in immediate window but why is that necessary? Thank you so much for all your generous help!

Comment: `mybook.worksheet(3)` was telling the code "No matter which sheet you're cycling through, use the third one in the workbook (for getting the ranges)" Switching that to `ws` tells the code to use the worksheet it's currently on in the cycle, as the one on which to find the ranges. For 3), it's not needed. The original code you posted in your question included a cycle through all the worksheets to print their names to the immediate window. I simple adjusted it so it prints the name of the current worksheet (I added the FNum as back reference to which file it came from).